# TeeChart for Monodroid

Tags: xamarin.android, teechart

I am trying to create an MonoDroid application integrated with TeeChart, i want to have an activity to hold a chart, and some other components, like textview, button, etc. Here is the code,

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Test);
            var testpanel = FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.MealChartPanel);

            Steema.TeeChart.TChart tChart1 = new Steema.TeeChart.TChart(this);

            Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bar bar1 = new Steema.TeeChart.Styles.Bar();
            tChart1.Series.Add(bar1);

            bar1.Add(3, "Pears", Color.Red);
            bar1.Add(4, "Apples", Color.Blue);
            bar1.Add(2, "Oranges", Color.Green);
            Steema.TeeChart.Themes.BlackIsBackTheme theme = new Steema.TeeChart.Themes.BlackIsBackTheme(tChart1.Chart);
            theme.Apply();

            testpanel.AddView(tChart1);
        }

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/MealChartPanel"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="100dip"
     android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
     android:layout_marginRight="5dip">
  </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

i used testpanel.AddView(tChart1); but nothing shows up there, how can i put the chart in the MealChartPanel linearlayout?

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you need to specify the chart dimensions. You can either set absolute pixel dimensions or use LayoutParams, for example:

```
  testpanel.AddView(tChart1, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FillParent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FillParent));
```

Comment: thanks, that works!Is there any detailed tutorial on the website? My co-worker has been working with teechart for monotouch, i am looking into his code for how to create a functional chart. But there does have some differences between the ones for monotouch and monodroid, like in monotouch, you could set ZoomScrollStyle, newChart.Chart.Aspect.ZoomScrollStyle = Steema.TeeChart.Drawing.Aspect.ZoomScrollStyles.Manual; but how to set this in monodorid?

Comment: @user1467537 Before the end of this month we will publish a new beta which will include tutorials. In MonoDroid you can set Zoom.Style, for example: tChart1.Zoom.Style = Steema.TeeChart.ZoomStyles.FullChart;

Comment: @user1467537 We just posted a beta update which includes full documentation and tutorials: http://www.steema.com/entry/116/TeeChart_.NET_Mono_for_Android_Library_BETA_update. We expect the next release being the final version.